# Inserting <bgsound> in Internet Explorer design mode

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser, tembeddedwb

I use this code to insert `<bgsound>` tag.

```
EmbeddedWB.Doc2.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<bgsound src="chimes.wav">');
```

Ignore for a second that `<bgsound>` is obsolete. I am working with it because in IE6 it works.

But nothing is present in the HTML source after above operation. At first I assumed something is wrong with above code until I tried this:

```
EmbeddedWB.Doc2.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<p>chimes.wav</p>');
```

At the above it correctly inserts `<p>` tag just after the `<body>` as it should. So why it won't insert `<bgsound>` then?

Also, something weird happens if I insert `<audio>` tag instead:

```
EmbeddedWB.Doc2.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<audio src="chimes.wav">some audio</audio>');
```

After this in source all I see is `some audio</audio>` without the opening tag.

I am beginning to wonder if the above doesn't work because I am in designer mode, is this possible cause why it won't insert `<bgaudio>`? Tried to insert some other tags too... for example comments also didn't work (`<!-- comment -->`).

**Edit:** Later I tried `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` in registry and after setting to 11001 (0x2AF9  Internet Explorer 11 mode) both `<audio>` and `<bgsound>` tags were inserted properly from edit mode. But it must be possible in older mode doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time here are some things I discovered:

- Internet Explorer control strips tags which it thinks are invalid when using `insertAdjacentHTML` or even `innerHTML`. There doesn't seem to be a way (that I know of) to insert any custom HTML code which the control will not try to validate. In IE6 where I was testing it it thinks that `<bgsound>` and `<audio>` tags are invalid so it strips them. It should not do that for `<bgsound>` but it does. Same goes for comments like `<!-- comment -->`.
- I found no way to insert the tag using `insertAdjacentHTML` or `innerHTML`. The best I could do is to wrap the sound tag inside some other tag - if I do that, the sound does play when inserted but it is still absent from source. Finally I inserted it directly into generated HTML before saving the HTML to disk (I tagged that sound was added and before saving HTML I inserted it into HTML without relying on MSHTML).
- Switching to standards mode e.g. by using registry entry `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` correctly inserts tags but won't work on some versions of Internet Explorer (I believe the minimum version would be IE9 for this to work) so it is less flexible.

I found no solution for this but at least I have some workarounds. Perhaps it helps someone in the future.